# обработка строк mysql

Tags: php, mysql

стоит задача заменить часть данных (varchar/datetime) содержащиеся в ячейке строкой "***"
для примера ячейка содержит фамилию "Петров" запрос должен выдать "П***в"
аналогично с датой `"03-11-2016" -> "03***16"`
Как должен выглядеть запрос?
Целесообразно для таких целей пользовать mysql, или правильней обрабатывать полученные данные в коде программы?

Comment: В принципе на клиенте конечно проще это сделать, регуляркой например. особого смысла прямо в БД делать нет, если конечно вам не надо это измененную информацию записать куда нибудь в БД. Если в БД то substr брать первые-последние символы и между ними *** вставлять

Answer (score 0):

Полностью запрос не буду писать, под рукой нет mysql чтобы проверить, вот посмотрите http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html

Используйте что-то вроде:
UPDATE tableName SET first_name = REPLACE(first_name, SUBSTRING(..., 2, 4), '***')

алгоритм простой, надо заменить вырезанную строку на ***
лучше сделать это на стороне базы, т.к. если у вас кол-во записей больше 1000000 то нет смысла нагружать этой операцией клиента, в базе все быстро выполнится